# Why do I get 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Tags: python, list

I get this error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

This is my function:

```
def power(x, y, bound):
    list, exp = [], []
    z = -1
    for i in range (1, bound):
        for j in range (1, bound):
            if x**i + y**j in range (bound):
                if x**i + y**j in list:
                    break
                else:
                    list.append(x**i + y**j)
                    z += 1
                    if z == 0:
                        exp.append(str(x**i + y**j)+" = " + str(x) + "^" + str(i) + " + " + str(y) + "^" + str(j))
                        break
                    if list[z] == max(list):
                        exp.append(str(x**i + y**j)+" = " + str(x) + "^" + str(i) + " + " + str(y) + "^" + str(j))
                    else:
                        for n in range(len(list)):
                            if (list[z] < list[n+1]) and (list[z] > list[n]):
                                exp.insert(n, str(x**i + y**j) + " = " + str(x) + "^" + str(i) + " + " + str(y) + "^" + str(j))
            else:
                break
    print("\nThe list of values:", sorted(list))
    print("\nExplaination:\n"+"\n".join(exp))
```

Call my function:

```
print("Input: Two positive integers x and y and the bound\nOutput: A list of values x^i + y^j bounded by bound\n(i and j are positive integers)\n")
x = int(input("Input x: "))
y = int(input("Input y: "))
bound = int(input("Input the bound: "))

power(x, y, bound)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so now you've changed your code and my previous answer has been invalidated.

Now your problem is here:

```
if (list[z] < list[n+1]) and (list[z] > list[n]):
```

with `n+1` because `n` comes from `for n in range(len(list)):` and eventually `n+1` will fall off the end of `list`.

You have to ask yourself what: `if (list[z] < list[n+1]) and (list[z] > list[n]):` actually means.

Comment: thank you, I forgot the condition that z must be > 1, I will delete my post now, sorry for wasting for time, thank you very much

Comment: this is the resulttt!!!!! I finally did it

Input x: 4
Input y: 6
Input the bound: 100

The list of values: [10, 22, 52, 70]

Explaination:
10 = 4^1 + 6^1
22 = 4^2 + 6^1
52 = 4^2 + 6^2
70 = 4^3 + 6^1

[Program finished]

Comment: If you make an answer and a question edit invalidates that answer, please roll the question back to the appropriate edit. Indeed, doing so now may be a kindness to James, who may have answered the original question.

Comment: If you could tidy up this page by deleting one of your answers and removing the meta-commentary from this one, that would help future readers make sense of the information presented.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just looking at the code in your function its obvious that `i` exceeds the size of `list`:

```
def power(x, y, bound):
    list, exp = [], []
```

`list` (don't use `list` as a variable name - it is a built-in and you've overwritten it here) starts off as an empty list.

```
i = -1
```

This line is useless since `i` is overwritten in the next line

```
for i in range (1, bound):
```

So `i` is now `1`

```
    list.append(x**i + y**j)
```

Now you seem to have appended the first value to `list` - now it has size `1`

```
        i += 1
```

Now you increment `i`, so it must be `2`

```
        if list[i] == max(list):
```

But now you attempt to index into `list` which raises an `IndexError`

Comment: @quamara sorry, I edit my code, it has the same problem

Comment: Please update your question with sample inputs which show the claimed problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way out of your difficulty is to catch the exception and print the relevant values.  Consider:

```
$ python3 <<EOF
a = []
try:
  i = 3
  a[i] = 0
except IndexError as oops:
  print( "%s: array is %d and index is %d" % (str(oops), len(a), i) )
EOF

list assignment index out of range: array is 0 and index is 3
```